# Creating two sdl window using vector emplace creates only one window

Tags: c++, sdl-2

Wrapping the sdl window in a class and creating a vector. Then emplacing two window objects creates only one window, though two is expected.

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <vector>
class Window
{
    SDL_Window*     m_window;
    SDL_Renderer*   m_renderer;
    int m_windowID;
public:
    Window( int w, int h, Uint32 mode = SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN )
    {

        m_window = SDL_CreateWindow( "", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, w, h, mode );
        m_renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( m_window , -1, SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC );
        m_windowID = SDL_GetWindowID(m_window);
    }
    ~Window()
    {
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(m_renderer);
        SDL_DestroyWindow( m_window);
    }
    void render()
    {
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(m_renderer, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff);
        SDL_RenderClear(m_renderer);
        SDL_RenderPresent(m_renderer);
    }
    void setTitle(const std::string& title)
    {
        SDL_SetWindowTitle(m_window, title.c_str());
    }
};
int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::vector<Window> window;
    window.emplace_back(/*width*/600,/*height*/480);
    window.emplace_back(/*width*/600,/*height*/480);
    window[0].setTitle(/*title*/"window-1");
    window[1].setTitle(/*title*/"window-2");
    SDL_Event event;
    bool quit = false;
    while( !quit )
    {
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) )
        {
            if( event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            {
                quit = true;
            }
        }
        for(auto& w: window)
        {
            w.render();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`SDL_CreateWindow` is being called twice yet only one window is being created, why?

Update: Setting the title of the window reveals that only the last created window remains.

Comment: Where does 'SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED' put the thing anyway?  How do you know they are not on top of each other?

Comment: The window can be moved, thus revealing another window under it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're violating The Rule of Three/Five.

After you push the second window, the vector is reallocated, and the first `Window` is "copied". New copy is preserved, but the destructor of the old one is called. New copy now points to the destroyed window. (also, the window is destroyed the second time at the end of the program, which probably causes undefined behaviour)

This wouldn't have happened if you used `std::unique_ptr` with appropriate deleter.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct SDLWindowDestroyer
{
    void operator()(SDL_Window* w) const
    {
        SDL_DestroyWindow(w);
    }
};

struct SDLRendererDestroyer
{
    void operator()(SDL_Renderer* r) const
    {
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(r);
    }
};

class Window
{
    std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window, SDLWindowDestroyer>     m_window;
    std::unique_ptr<SDL_Renderer, SDLRendererDestroyer>   m_renderer;
    int m_windowID;
public:
    Window( int w, int h, const char* name, Uint32 mode = SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN ) :
        m_window(SDL_CreateWindow( name, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, w, h, mode )),
        m_renderer(SDL_CreateRenderer( m_window.get() , -1, SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC )),
        m_windowID(SDL_GetWindowID(m_window.get()))
    {

    }

    void render()
    {
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(m_renderer.get(), 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff);
        SDL_RenderClear(m_renderer.get());
        SDL_RenderPresent(m_renderer.get());
    }
};
```